# SQL - Display unique result or word if multiple results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm searching for a specific SQL Query.

I have two tables : "DOCUMENT" and "DOCUMENT_CONTENT" similar to this :

```
DOCUMENT

Number   |  Date       |
---------+-------------+
48796    |  21/04/2015 |
48797    |  21/04/2015 | 

DOCUMENT_CONTENT

Number   |  Product_Code  |  Supplier  |  Quantity  | 
---------+----------------+------------+------------+
48796    |  8008554       |  SupplierA |    3       |
48796    |  8008579       |  SupplierA |    4       |
48796    |  9870560       |  SupplierA |    5       |
48797    |  8008554       |  SupplierA |    7       |
48797    |  8081784       |  SupplierB |    1       |
48797    |  8217471       |  SupplierA |    23      |
```

In this example i have two documents 48796 and 48797 with several products code, suppliers and quantities.

For the document number 48796, the supplier is only "SupplierA" but for the 48797 there are SupplierA and SupplierB.

I want to generate this result :

```
DOCUMENT

Number   |  Date       |  Supplier   |
---------+-------------+-------------+
48796    |  21/04/2015 |  SupplierA  |
48797    |  21/04/2015 |   several   |
```

It means, if in document content there are different supplier, i display "several" else i display the supplier name.

I have no idea how i can do that in a sql query. If someone have an idea, i like to know it.

Thanks.

Comment: CASE WHEN.. is what you need

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The trick here is to do aggregation and test the results in a case:

```
select d.*, dc.supplier
from DOCUMENT d join
     (select dc.number,
             (case when min(dc.Supplier) = max(dc.Supplier) then min(dc.Supplier)
                   else 'Several'
              end) as supplier
      from DOCUMENT_CONTENT dc
      group by dc.number
     ) dc
     on dc.number = d.number;
```

This uses a subquery to calculate the new supplier name, so you can easily put in all the columns from `document`.  If you could have missing documents in `document_content`, then you would want to use a `left join`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select Case when count(Supplier) = 1 then Max(supplier) else 'several' end
 from DOCUMENT D Inner Join DOCUMENT_CONTENT DC on D.Number = DC.Number
Group by D.Date , D.Number
```